# Regex - Find 8 digit number in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to extract an 8 digit number from a string using regex.

Test strings are:

1. `hi 82799162`
2. `236232 (82342450)`
3. `test data 8979`

Required respective output should be

1. `82799162`
2. `82342450`
3. `null`

I have tried following code:

- `preg_match('/[0-9]{8}$/', $string, $match);`
- `preg_match('/\d{8}$/', $string, $match);`

But neither retrieves the number from `236232 (82342450)`.

Comment: Remove your trailing `$`.

Comment: thanks, it worked. I'm regex noob.

Comment: What is expected result for: `123456789`?

Comment: it should be discarded, as it is not exactly 8-digits long. I have accepted Nimeshka's answer btw.

Comment: Then you should accept @Valdi_Bo 's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with your `$` sign, and it is used to indicate the end of your expression. So basically, with that expression, you are looking for a string which ends with a 8 digit number. But in your second test string; `'236232 (82342450)'`, ends with a bracket, and therefore it doesn't match the criteria (does not end with a number).

So remove the trailing `$` and it will work.

```
preg_match('/[0-9]{8}/',$string,$match);
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 8):

If a regex is to capture **exactly** 8 digits, is must contain:

- `\d{8}` as a central part,
- a "before" condition, ensuring that no digit occurs **before** your match,
- an "after" condition, ensuring that no digit occurs **after** your match.

One of possible solutions is to use *negative lookbehind* / *lookahead*:

```
(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)
```

Another option is *word boundary assertions* (at both ends):

```
\b\d{8}\b
```

I think, regex like `[0-9]{8}` is not enough, as it captures also
**first 8 digits** from a **longer** sequence of digits.
Are you happy with that?

Comment: Can you please help me? The second Option works exactly, but what I want is to search for 8 digit word which may contain number or alphabets and after that, it should end with .php and must contain only 8 characters neither 7 nor 6.

Comment: If you want to match not only numbers but also letters, change `\d` to
`[a-z\d]`. Then add `\.php`. So the whole regex should be
`\b[a-z\d]{8}\.php\b`, with `i` (case insensitive) option. I assume that the mentioned number of chars pertains to the part **before** ".php".
Or maybe **the whole** string should contain 8 chars?
In this case the regex should be `\b[a-z\d]{4}\.php\b` (4 digits or letters,
then ".php", totally 8 chars).